# Lambda function to copy file one s3 to another while uploading

Tags: python, aws-lambda

How to copy a file with csv in to another bucket

I have 3 buckets in AWS a)test  b)testjson  c)testcsv

I have upload data.json and data.csv to test bucket

After Uploading the file below things are happend

1. data.json file is copied to testjson bucket
2. data.csv file is copied  to testcsv bucket

data.json

```
{
"emp_id": "3",
"Name" : "Madk"
"Company": "FB"
}
```

data.csv

```
emp_id,Name,Company
3,Madk,FB
```

In this lambda handler only I need to copy .json into another bucket and .csv into another bucket

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear to me, but I seem to guess that both objects have been uploaded into the a)test bucket (not b or c).
In that case I would remove them from the bucket first:

```
s3.delete_object(Bucket='test', Key='data.json')
s3.delete_object(Bucket='test', Key='data.csv')
```

Then I would upload them to the right buckets:

```
s3.upload_file(Filename='data.json', Bucket='testjson', Key='data.json')
s3.upload_file(Filename='data.csv', Bucket='testjson', Key='data.csv')
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work or any issues. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

> Create a copy of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3.

then [copy_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) is the way to go in boto3.

Sample code

```
import boto3

bucket_from = "test"
bucket_to_json = "testjson"
bucket_to_csv = "testcsv"

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

name = 'data.json'

s3.meta.client.copy_object(
    Bucket=bucket_to_json,
    CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_from, 'Key': name},
    Key=name
)

name = 'data.csv'

s3.meta.client.copy_object(
    Bucket=bucket_to_csv,
    CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_from, 'Key': name},
    Key=name
)
```